# Apple Watch page based interface overflowing on initial controller

Tags: ios, scroll, overflow, watchkit, apple-watch

While creating an Apple Watch app I noticed something strange.

My Initial Controller is always vertically overflowing when using a page based interface. If I remove the 'next-page segue' everything works fine.

The strange thing is that even empty controllers will overflow and all the following controllers won't. It seems to appear on the initial controller only.

Is there someway to stop this vertical overflow?

[image: 38MM Apple Watch Simulator Screenshot]

Comment: Note: I've already tried to clean the build folder and reset content and settings on the simulators. Both the 38MM and 42MM Watches have this problem.

Comment: Seemingly, you're not the only one who's having this issue. Me and someone else are having the exact same problem.

Comment: I'm having this issue as well where my image is getting stretched down really far. Xcode 6.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just verified @Ashraf's findings...this appears to be a regression with the Xcode 6.2 GM release (this was not happening in Xcode 6.2 beta 5). I have tried multiple workarounds to no avail. I'd highly suggest filing a Serious Bug radar on Apple's [bug reporting system](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Hi @Maarten1909, is the answer I provided sufficient? If yes, would you mind upvoting and marking as the answer?