# Why the main view become scrollable on WatchKit app?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, watchkit

I've made the size of the main view to fit the screen on the WatchKit app, so the user don't need to scroll down to see the content, but the problem is when i rely that view with another one using **Next Page**, this later become scrollable and has 3 times its size in height.

Is it just a bug on Xcode? or is there is something i need to configure to fix it?

*P.S.This issue happens just when i use the **Next Page** feature.*

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the simulator using **Next Page**:

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the simulator without using **Next Page**:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the Xcode 6.2 GM. See this other thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29049643/apple-watch-page-based-interface-overflowing-on-initial-controller/29052192#29052192). I would certainly suggest filing a radar with Apple's [bug reporting system](http://bugreport.apple.com).